# Why is COSMOS is throttling when RU is not crossed

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

From my understanding if the RUs exceeds more than what is set there will be throttling. but from what I see below this is has not even crossed the RU threshold (actual value 2457) but I am getting HTTP429.[image]

But in another collection I see that it has cross the RU threshold but there is no throttling.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess "Max consumed RU/s per partion key range" is not aggregated over 1 minute. So you have more than one request in that exact throttled minute and it sums up with the request for 2457.